# JSS - selector for all nested grand children elements

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, jss

First of all, I realize what a basic question this is, and for sure it has been asked before, I just can not find an answer to it.

Using JSS, I would like to have all the child elements, for example of `<b>`, and set a specific color to them.
The `<b>` might be at any nesting level of root.

By trying the following, it selects only the immediate `<b>` childs of the root element:

```
const style = () => ({
    root: {
        "& b": {
            color: red;
        }
    }
})
```

So how can I select all children, regardless of nesting level?

Comment: What CSS does this compile to on your machine?

Comment: By inspecting any <b> element that is a descendant of root, there are no "color" styles on it at all, unless the <b> is a direct child of root.